# A text book on how to design a language

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

I'm working on a scripting language and would like to write a compiler / interpreter for my language.

I've desited to do the compiler in standart ML

My question now is, is there a "pattern" for doing this sorta design process?

I've written a java-compiler from scratch as a part of a computerscience course, but that was sorta cheating, since the language was given, meaning that there was reference implementations and syntax, grammars and other specs given.

If starting from scratch, only having a problem domain how does one get started?

I'm looking for a book or a tutorial on the subject.

Comment: Are you looking for a book on functional _language_ design, compiler design for writing compilers in a _functional_ manner, or guides on how to compile functional languages?

Comment: P.s., my advice if it's the second is, don't.  There are already a bunch of good functional languages you can practice compiling, "core ML," might be one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic books on modern compiler construction in functional languages are:

- [Modern Compiler Implementation in ML](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~appel/modern/ml/)
- [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/)
- [Implementing Functional Languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/pj-lester-book/)
- [Practical Foundations of Programming Languages](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf)

Comment: Also mentioning "Compiling with Continuations," is probably a fine idea.

Comment: Than you, I've actually been reading your blog for some time :) 
I've looked at Apples book, but it still has the problem of the "tiger" language being pre-defined. Are there books on how to design the language?

Comment: +1 for Implementing Functional Languages. Not necessarily a how-to-design book, but a great book for crawling inside the head of a language.

Answer (score 2):

[Concepts, Techniques and Models of Computer Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262220695). This book is not directly about how to design a language, but it is an in-depth exploration of the features of one interesting language (Oz), how they interact, and how they enable various usage patterns and features. It is excellent for giving a sense of what the implications of various design decisions and capabilities are. Reading a few such books, observing the resulting languages, and synthesizing from them is a decent way to go about learning how to design a language.

Similarly, but a lot more pragmatically, [Programming Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644) does a great job of explaining how language features enable style.

A lot of language design is ultimately taste and good sense. Reading in-depth explorations of existing languages is a good way to develop and hone such taste.